# Passing $host as a directory with nginx proxypass

Tags: nginx

I have this snippet working in my test env. But when added to the production env it doesn't appear to be capturing the $host. Both confs are identical

```
location /testtesttest {
     proxy_pass https://newcdn.com/apple-pay-certs/$host/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association.txt;
}
```